# kickstart.script: Error code 127 running the kickstart script

Tags: bash, shell, anaconda

during a OS install i am using a custom kickstart which works fine till this command on the %post segment:

`ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml`

This generates an error:

> /mnt/sysimage/bin/python 3.11: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.11.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Just for more context requirements.yml content:

```
collections:
- ansible.posix
- community.docker
- community.general
- ansible.windows
- community.windows
- chocolatey.chocolatey
```

This should work fine but anaconda fails to run this.